# Can __getattr__() determine whether it is part of a nested sequence of dotted attribute accesses?

Tags: python

For my application (modelling hardware registers with named bit fields), I'd like to support syntax like this to access the fields:

```
device.REG0.F0 = 1    # access some defined subset of bits
print device.REG0.F0
```

but also allow access to the whole register as an integer:

```
device.REG0 = 123     # access all bits
print device.REG0
```

To support this, `__getattr__()` on the outer object needs to determine whether it is part of an access to some innermost field (in which case return the register object for further `__get/setattr__()` processing), or simply an access to a whole register (in which case return the integer value).

I have a half-assed proof-of-concept working by looking at the source text of caller's context via the `inspect` module, but it's easily broken.  Is there some more reliable way to get maybe AST or other syntactic information about the 'current spot' in the code?

Or, are there alternative approaches which give the desired syntax:

- some way for an object to implicitly yield an integer in appropriate contexts?
- some way to simulate properties of a property?
- some other magic?

Note: I'm aware that I can achieve the required functionality with different syntax.  It's this specific syntax which is important to me.

Comment: You would need to create your own class that inherits from `int`.  When you create `device`, you need to create an instance of *your* `int` class, and give it an attribute called `FO`

Comment: There seems to be a problem in that you're trying to create a mutable integer. If you access and store `REG0`, and then modify `REG0` via new access to the device, then what should happen to the previously stored `REG0`. Should it remain as it was (in the state when it was accessed), or change to reflect the new value of the register?